# Summation of expression with factorials

Tags: summation, factorial

Is there an easy way to evaluate the following sum without summing all the terms one by one?

$$\Large\sum_{i=1}^{10} {i! \cdot i}$$

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}i!\times i = \sum_{i=1}^{10}[(i + 1)! - i!] = 11! - 1!$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sum:

$$\large\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i! \cdot i}$$

can be proven to be equal to $(n+1)! - 1$ using inductive reasoning.

For some property,
$$P(n) = \large\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i! \cdot i}$$
using $P(1) = (1+1)! - 1$ to be a basis, assume $P(k) = (k+1)! - 1$.

Then, prove $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$, which means $P(k+1) = (k+2)! - 1$, to be true.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} i! \cdot i & = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} i! \cdot i + (k + 1)(k + 1)!\\
                           & = (k + 1)! - 1 + (k + 1)(k + 1)! & \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
                           & = (1 + k + 1)(k + 1)! - 1\\
                           & = (k + 2)(k + 1)! - 1\\
                           & = (k + 2)! - 1
\end{align*}

Therefore, $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$. $P(n)$ holds $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$.

> [See this question for source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698097/proving-sum-i-1n-ii-n1-1-by-mathematical-induction)

We can now rewrite the original sum as

$$\large\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i! \cdot i} = (n + 1)! - 1$$

Therefore, $n=10$ is simply

$$\large\sum_{i=1}^{10}{i! \cdot i} = (10 + 1)! - 1 = 11! - 1 = 39916799$$